# C# Rotativa ActionAsPDF change text-direction right to left

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rotativa

i use  Rotativa.ActionAsPdf to convert View to Pdf it works perfectly 
but the problem how to change text-direction right to left?

here my code:

```
    public ActionResult ExportPDF(ReportsModel RM)
    {
        string id = Session["Pat_id"].ToString();
        string subPath = "~/Attachment/" + id;
        string link;
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));
        if (!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));

      return  new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PhysicalExaminationSummaryToPDF", new { id = id })
        {
            FileName = "PhysicalExaminationSummary.pdf",
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.Letter,
            PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 }
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I solve it
should to add in view style direction:rtl

```
<style>
    #status_quest {
        direction:rtl;
    }
</style>
```

when convert view to Pdf does not relate to CSS libraries